# How to create a Handlebars helper that check for the file extension

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Hello i´m trying to get check if the extension of my files is an JPG, PNG, PDF, DOC or Excel, to display a icon according to the file extension.

```
var info = [
  {
    IdTrnx = 1234567
    files = [{
      0:"pic.jpg",
      1:"file.pdf"
    }]
  },
  {
    IdTrnx = 7654321
    files = [{
      0:"pic.png",
      1:"file.doc"
    }]
  }
]
```

Thats my object.

This is my curent handlebars.

```
<table id="tb-tickets" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field=""># Transacción</th>
            <th data-field="">Tickets</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each this}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{IdTrnx}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{#each files}}
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fileModaltickets" data-file="{{this}}" id="getFile"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></button>
                    {{/each}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Rigth now is displaying the same icon for every file.
how can i create a handlebar helper to check for the extension and set the icon to the correct extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you declare your helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkExtension', function(item, options) {
    var regex = '/.*jpg|JPG|png|PNG|doc|DOC|xls|XLS|pdf|PDF$/';
    if (item.match(regex)) {
      return "checked";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
});
```

and here is the use in your template :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fileModaltickets" data-file="{{this}}" id="getFile" {{checkExtension this}}><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></button>
```

This will add the word "checked" if your file has the right file extension